# Codeigniter doesn't show the view on Live site, but it does show on localhost

Tags: codeigniter

My site is working on localhost but not on the live site.

this is a part of my code:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('dirhandler_model', '', true);
    $this->load->model('database_model', '', true);
    $this->output->enable_profiler(false);
}

function view($site, $data = array()) {
    $settings = $this->db->query(sprintf("select s_id, value, property from setting order by s_id "));
    $r_settings = $settings->result();
    $data['settings'] = $r_settings;
    $data['photos'] = $this->dirhandler_model->getPhotoFolder();
    $data['hmenu'] = $this->database_model->getMenu();
    t($data);
    $this->load->view('inc/header', $data); # when I Comment this out
    $this->load->view($site, $data);
    $this->load->view('inc/footer', $data); 
}
```

you see the t($data);, that's a print_r of data.
It shows the data in the print_r, but if I remove the t($data);
I get a blank page, also if I view the source on the live site: I see one line and that is blank.
When I comment out the header and I view the source, then I see HTML data

When I run this on localhost, it works fine.

I uploaded all folders to the live site via FTP.
I don't use hooks
error reporting is on but no errors.

my header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
        <meta name="description" content="<?php print $settings[2]->value ?>">
        <title><?php print $settings[0]->value ?></title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php print asset_url()?>img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="<?php print asset_url()?>img/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print asset_url()?>externals/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print asset_url()?>externals/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print asset_url()?>externals/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print asset_url()?>externals/lightbox/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Euphoria+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php print asset_url()?>css/style.css">
        <script src="<?php print asset_url()?>externals/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php print asset_url()?>externals/jquery_ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<?php print asset_url()?>externals/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 left_header">&nbsp;</div>
                <div id="title" class="col-md-7">
                    <h1><?php print $settings[0]->value ?></h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 right_header">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills col-md-7 col-md-offset-3">
                    <?php 
                    foreach ($hmenu as $menuItem) {
                        $active = '';
                        if (empty($this->uri->total_segments())) {
                            $active = '';
                        }
                        elseif (!empty($this->uri->segment_array()[4]) && url_title($this->uri->segment_array()[4]) == url_title($menuItem->menu_label )) {
                            $active = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="fa fa-arrow-circle-down"></span>';
                        } 

                        $menuLabel = ($menuItem->c_id == 1 ? site_url() : site_url('/home/content/'.$menuItem->c_id.'/'.url_title($menuItem->menu_label)));
                        printf ('
                        <li role="presentation">
                            <a href="%s">%s%s</a>
                        </li>
                        ', $menuLabel, $menuItem->menu_label, $active);
                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <?php print $photos ?>
                    <i style="color: #FFA61C">(Wissel met F11 tussen voledige scherm en normaal scherm.)</i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7" id="main-container">
                <div class="crumb text-center">
                    <?php print set_breadcrumb() ?><br />
                </div>
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: Sounds like an error in the view itself, try loading the same view with no content, This can be due to different php versions that interpret code slightly differently. what's not error in one, is indeed an error in another. double check that the view loads correctly

Comment: Yes Patrick, I empty the header and it works!
Now I can findout where the bottleneck is

Comment: My first guess would be `<?php print asset_url()?>` , notice how you have no space before the php closing? I had some bad experience with that before

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data['header '] = $this->load->view('inc/header', $data,true); 
$data['footer'] = $this->load->view('inc/footer', $data,true); 
$this->load->view($site, $data);
```

Comment: If I add the blolean true to the header, then it doesn't work on localhost. I think there is some issue in the header, I'll edit my question, I'll put the header.php